# Memory leak when calling `fwrite` function from `data.table`

Tags: r, memory, memory-leaks, data.table, fwrite

I have a top level function in my package that performs a variety of data cleaning tasks on a directory of `.csv` files. It reads in the `.csv`, converts it to lower case, converts columns to specified types, adds and removes columns, etc.

The top level function looks like:

```
top <- function(path, csv = FALSE, rds = FALSE) {  
  files <- get_file_or_dir(path) # returns a character vector of matching file(s)
  dirs <- parse_files(files) # Creates directories and moves files into them
  lapply(dirs, do_dir, csv, rds)
}
```

This calls:

```
do_dir <- function(dir, csv, rds) {
   lapply(fs::dir_ls(dir), function(file) {
     conv_to_standard(file, csv, rds)
  })
}
```

which calls:

```
conv_to_standard <- function(file, csv, rds) {

  df <- data.table::fread(file, sep = "\t", colClasses = character(), showProgress = FALSE)
  setup(df)
  conv_type_cols(df)
  conv_special_cols(df)
  conv_factor_cols(df)
  conv_order_cols(df)
  output(df, file, csv, rds)
  return(NULL)
}
```

The top level parameter `csv` and `rds` are boolean values that indicate to produce either a .csv or .rds file as an output (or both). The relevant function is the `output` function:

```
output <- function(df, file, csv, rds) {
  output_csv(df, file, csv)
  output_rds(df, file, rds)
}

output_rds <- function(df, file, rds) {
  if(rds) {
    saveRDS(df, file = paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(file), "_clean.rds", sep = ""))
  }
}

output_csv <- function(df, file, csv) {
  if(csv) {
    data.table::fwrite(df, file = paste(tools::file_path_sans_ext(file), "_clean.csv", sep = ""), showProgress = FALSE)
  }
}
```

When I run `top("../test/")` in a directory containing 15 `.csv` files, my function completes without memory allocation issues and uses only 1-2GB of RAM at any given time. However, as soon as I set `csv = TRUE`, I end up with memory allocation errors and failures after 4-5 `.csv` files have been processed. You can see the profile of the first case below:

[image: without fwrite]

You can see the case when `csv = TRUE` below (which only calls the function that calls `fwrite`), I start to have serious memory allocation errors where memory in the `lapply` loop is never deallocated. This eventually results in my function failing due to lack of memory to allocate:

[image: with fwrite]

The only difference between the last two examples is the calling of the `output_csv` function. Is there any reason this would be leading to a failure to deallocate memory?

Does `fwrite` open a file connection that I need to explicitly close?

UPDATE:
After a lot of digging, I narrowed the problem down to a single line of code:

```
`%^%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
    levels<-`(factor(stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(lhs,"  ", " ")), rhs)
}
```

When I changed the function to this (which does the same thing), the problem completely went away:

```
`%^%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  x <- factor(stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(lhs,"  ", " "))
  levels(x) <- rhs
  return(x)
}
```

This is a very bizarre bug and I have no idea why it is happening. Even though I'm no longer having memory allocation issues, I would love to hear any guesses about why this happened.

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)
```

Comment: 1. where is example data? 2. did you try running that in R console rather than R IDE? 3. did you try to reproduce problem on non-Windows OS?